# Django SQLite3 unable to open database file

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite3

Настроил сервер для работы Django приложения по этой инструкции https://djbook.ru/examples/62/

Вышла проблема, метод GET работает отлично данные выводятся, но когда я пытаюсь выполнить метод PUT, POST у меня выходит ошибка

```
OperationalError at /api/video/detail/44/
unable to open database file
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Права вот

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root       4096 Oct 16 15:08 app_store
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root       4096 Oct 16 15:07 categories
drwxr-xr-x 5 root     root       4096 Oct 16 15:08 chat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 299008 Oct 18 18:40 db.sqlite3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root        669 Oct 16 15:07 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root       4096 Oct 16 15:07 media
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root       4096 Oct 16 15:07 playlists
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root       4096 Oct 16 15:07 profiles
drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data   4096 Oct 18 18:09 my_application
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root       4096 Oct 16 15:07 videos
```

Кстати ещё момент если я запуская сервер django (python3 manage.py runserver ip:port) то всё работает отлично.

Comment: Я бы перепроверил настройки nginx

Comment: проблема при запуске за nginx? включите debug, посмотрите логи gunicorn, проверьте владельца всех файлов, пользователей, под которыми крутятся nginx и gunicorn

Comment: Всем спасибо.
Да я решил проблему. Я немного сглупил, я не назначил правильные права директории в которой лежит весь проект.